# Show that the sequence $\left\lbrace{z_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ is convergent on $R^n$, with ${z_{k}}\rightarrow x+y$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\lbrace{x_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ and $\left\lbrace{y_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ two convergent sequences in ${R}^n$, with ${x_{k}}\rightarrow x$ and ${y_{k}}\rightarrow y$. Let  $z_{k}:=x_{k}+y_{k}$ $\forall_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$. Show that the sequence $\left\lbrace{z_{k}}\right\rbrace_{k\in\mathbf{N}}$ is convergent on $R^n$, with ${z_{k}}\rightarrow x+y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing like BW or compactness is required. It comes from the triangle inequality:

$|z_k -(x+y)| \leq |x_k -x| +|y_k -y|.$ Then use the definition of convergence. I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, if it is very useful